# Удаления элемента массива указателей

Tags: c

Есть динамический массив указателей

```
char ** pointer = (char **) calloc(count,sizeof(char*));
```

на строки.
Нужно удалять из него элементы, т.е. фактически освобождать память на которую указывает данный указатель, а после присваивать указателю `NULL`

Проблема в том, что после, при выводе данных выводит "левые" данные, хотя по идее адрес данного указателя должен быть `0x0`, при дебаге указатель указывает на другой адрес, не `0х0`

```
void delete_elem(char ** p){
    char ** p_str = p;
    free(*p_str);
    p=NULL;
}
```

Comment: а вы уверены что удалять надо только первый элемент? и да, `p=NULL;` бессмысленно, это локальная переменная.

Comment: я не удаляю первый элемент, я передаю в функцию адрес элемента массива, который нужно удалить. 
Тогда если массив будет глобальным присваивать `NULL` будет иметь смысл ?

Comment: @Hardc0re Не ясно, то ли вы хотите удалить весь динамически распределенный массив указателей, то ли ту память, на которую указывает определенный элемент массива.

Comment: я хотел во первых освободить память на которую указывал указатель, а после присвоить указателю `NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы этого хотите?

```
void delete_elem(char *** p){
    free(*p);
    *p=NULL;
}

char ** pointer = (char **) calloc(count,sizeof(char*));

delete_elem(&pointer);
```

Только у вас точно память под `count` указателей на `char` не выделялась? Через `pointer[i]`? Ее освобождать точно не надо?

Comment: @pavel Все, на сегодня хватит, заработался. Спасибо!